# Parse Error: (incorrect indentation or misplaced bracket)

Tags: parsing, haskell, ghc

I'm starting out to learn Haskell. Even though I'm a dunce extraordinaire, I am intent on making this work. The error I received is listed as the title. This is the code that I wrote to try to implement the behavior of replicating a list (n) times and concatenating its new length as a new list. Now I have a basic understanding of how parsing works in Haskell, below my original code I will give example of some modified code to see if my understanding on parsing is adequate. My question for now is how I can properly indent or structure my block in order to not receive this error (is that specific enough :O) -- is there a piece of information I'm missing when it comes to creating instances and formatting? PLEASE DO NOT TELL ME OR OFFER SUGGESTIONS IF YOU NOTICE THAT MY CURRENT INSTANCE OR MAIN FUNCTION ARE SYNTACTICALLY WRONG. I want to figure it out and will deal with that GHC error when I get to it. (I hope that's the proper way to learn). BUT if I could ask for anyone's help in getting past this first obstacle in understanding proper formatting, I'd be grateful.

```
module Main where 
import Data.List

n :: Int 
x :: [Char]

instance Data stutter n x where
   x = []
   n = replicate >>=  x : (n:xs)
   stutter >>= main = concat [x:xs]

let stutter 6 "Iwannabehere"  -- <-- parse error occurs here!!!
```

--Modified code with appropriate brackets, at least where I think they go.

```
module Main where 
import Data.List

n :: Int 
x :: [Char]

instance Data stutter n x where{
   ;x = []
   ;n = replicate >>=  x : (n:xs)
   ;stutter >>= main = concat [x:xs]
;
};let stutter 6 "Iwannabehere" -- there should be no bracket of any kind at the end of this
```

I placed the 'let' expression on the outside of the block, I don't believe it goes inside and I also receive a parsing error if I do that. Not correct but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: There are lots of issues with this code.  Type signatures need to be followed by the definition, so `n :: Int` followed by a signature for `x` is invalid.  Second, your declaring an `instance Data` but `Data` is not a type class in this scope.  Third, top level declarations can not be expressions, meaning `let` is not a valid top level construct.  Perhaps you should try reading `LYAH` and asking one question at a time and building up.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson `n::Int` followed by `x::Int` is perfectly valid - the definitions have to be in the same file, there's no requirement of them being directly adjacent to the signatures though.

Comment: `let variable = value` is only for GHCi and `do`-blocks. You'll want to simply write `variable = value`. To find out more about everything to do with Haskell, I'd reccomend visiting http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters.

Comment: @Cubic Indeed, what was I thinking.

Comment: @AJFarmar, it's also for local definitions, of course.

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed, but that's only if followed by an `in`, which isn't included here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the `instance Data stutter n x` is supposed to be, the `instance XYZ where` syntax is used solely for typeclasses, but you have a couple syntax errors here.

First of all, while GHC says that the error is on `let stutter 6 "Iwannabehere"`, your first error occurs before that with `stutter >>= main = concat [x:xs]`.  A single `=` sign is reserved for assignments, which are merely definitions.  You can have assignments at the top level, inside a `where` block, or inside a `let` block (the `where` includes typeclass instance definitions).  You can't have an assignment be part of an expression like `x >>= y = z`.

Your next syntax error is the `let` itself.  `let` blocks can not appear at the top level, they only appear within another definition.  You use `let` in GHCi but the reasons for that are outside the scope of this answer.  Suffice to say that entering expression in GHCi is not equivalent to the top level of a source file.

Next, if you were to use a `let` block somewhere, it can only contain definitions.  The syntax looks more like

```
let <name> [<args>] = <definition>
    [<name> [<args>] = <definition>]
in <expression>
```

And this whole block makes an expression.  For example, you could write

```py
def f(x, y, z):
    w = x + y + z
    u = x - y - z
    return w * u
```

in Python, and this would be equivalent to the Haskell function definition

```
f x y z = let w = x + y + z
              u = x - y - z
          in w * u
```

It only defines local variables.  There is another form when you're using it inside `do` blocks where you can exclude the `in <expression>` part, such as

```
main = do
    name <- getLine
    let message = if length name > 5 then "short name" else "long name"
        goodbye n = putStrLn ("Goodbye, " ++ n)
    putStrLn message
    goodbye name
```

Note that there is no need to use `in` here.  You can if you want, it just means you have to start a new `do` block:

```
main = do
    name <- getLine
    let message = ...
        goodbye n = ...
    in do
        putStrLn message
        goodbye name
```

And this isn't as pretty.

Hopefully this points you more towards correct syntax, but it looks like you have some misunderstandings about how Haskell works.  Have you looked at Learn You a Haskell?  It's a pretty gentle and fun introduction to the language that can really help you learn the syntax and core ideas.

Comment: bheklir, nothing but respect for you. You are the type of haskeller I aspire to be even though I suck. I have taken a look and read Learn You a Haskell. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction with the syntactically correct definition of 'let'. I still have a lot to catch up on and I don't know why I am not "getting it". I'm sad this can't be my full-time focus bc I'm job hunting. Thanks again.

Comment: @dgomez1092 I first saw Haskell about 6 years ago.  I poked at the language for a while, but put it down for most of college.  I came back to it when I had a slow period at an internship.  After hammering on it a lot for a few months, I finally thought I had "gotten it".  A couple years later now and I'm still not sure I'm done getting it.  Haskell is a weird and difficult language for many people, but it's worth it to stick through it!  It's not that you suck, it's just that you need more practice.  Just keep asking questions, keep practising, and the pieces will start falling in place.

Answer (score 1):

Your parse error is from the `let` keyword. Remove it and no error related to that will occur. `let x = y` is only relevant in GHCi and `do`-blocks, neither of which is relevant at this point. Essentially, just replace it with this line:

```
theWordIGet = stutter 6 "Iwannabehere"
```

Secondly, `instance` keyword in Haskell has *absolutley nothing* to do with what you want to do at this stage. This is not how Haskell functions are defined, which is what I'm guessing you want to do. This is what you're wanting to do to create a `stutter` function, assuming it simply repeats a string `n` times.

```
stutter :: Int -> String -> String
stutter n x = concat (replicate n x)
```

You'll also want to remove the type declarations for the (out-of-scope) values `n` and `x`: they're not objects, they're arguments for a function, which has its own signature determining the types of `n` and `x` within a function call.

Lastly, I imagine you will want to print the value of `stutter 6 "Iwannabehere"` when the program is executed. To do that, just add this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (stutter 6 "Iwannabehere")
```

In conclusion, I *implore* you to start from scratch and read 'Learn You a Haskell' online [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com), because you're going off in entirely the wrong direction - the program you've quoted is a jumble of expressions that *could* have a meaning, but are in the wrong place entirely. The book will show you the syntax of Haskell much better that I can write about in this one answer, and will explain fully how to make your program behave in the way you expect.